# Python Turtle pen colour

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I call `t.pencolor('83, 58, 27')` (turtle is imported as t) I get the `TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: 83, 58, 27` even though I have (I think) changed my colour mode.

```
t.colormode(255)    
t.pencolor('83, 58, 27')
```

I run python 2.7 on OS 10.9

Comment: [turtle.pencolor in Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor)

Need to pass a parameter of string: "brown" or "#32c18f"
Or type tuple: (0.2, 0.8, 0.55)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing in a *string* with three colors, where you need to pass the three colors as three separate integer arguments, like this:

```
t.pencolor(83, 58, 27)
```

There are multiple ways to use `pencolor`, from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor):

> Four input formats are allowed:
>
> pencolor()
>       Return the current pencolor as color specification string or as a tuple (see example). May be used as input to another
>   color/pencolor/fillcolor call.
>
> pencolor(colorstring)
>       Set pencolor to colorstring, which is a Tk color specification string, such as "red", "yellow", or "#33cc8c".
>
> pencolor((r, g, b))
>       Set pencolor to the RGB color represented by the tuple of r, g, and b. Each of r, g, and b must be in the range 0..colormode, where
>   colormode is either 1.0 or 255 (see colormode()).
>
> pencolor(r, g, b)
>       Set pencolor to the RGB color represented by r, g, and b. Each of r, g, and b must be in the range 0..colormode.

So you can also send in a *tuple* of your colors, but again they need to be integers not strings:

```
t.pencolor((83, 58, 27))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think you can delete the apostrophes as it is not a string, but a value.
Like this:
`t.pencolor(83, 58, 27)`.