# Is there a way to have rgb colors in Python3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I was trying to specify the RGB colors to make the program generate random colors. I was trying how to do RGB colors however, it would show an error that it had bad color input, more specifically, "raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (0, 255, 0)"

```
from random import randint

myPen = turtle.Turtle()
myPen.ht()
myPen.speed(0)
myPen.pencolor(0,255,0)
myPen.begin_fill()
points = [[-500,-400],[0,500],[500,-400]] #size of triangle
def getMid(p1,p2):
    return ( (p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2) #find midpoint

def triangle(points,depth):

    myPen.up()
    myPen.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
    myPen.down()
    myPen.goto(points[1][0],points[1][1])
    myPen.goto(points[2][0],points[2][1])
    myPen.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])

    if depth>0:
        z=(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
        myPen.fillcolor(z)
        triangle([points[0],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   depth-1)
        triangle([points[1],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[1], points[2])],
                   depth-1)
        triangle([points[2],
                         getMid(points[2], points[1]),
                         getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   depth-1)



triangle(points,7)
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: RGB where? In a picture? I see no imports - no idea what pen you use ...

Comment: So sorry! I was using turtle as MyPen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20320921 suggests you should check your color mode. If it is using the 0.0..0.1 model, those colors are invalid.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, and self answer, imply something that isn't true.  Python turtle is RGB by default.  What it isn't is *integer* color values.  The default is RGB *floating* values:

```
from turtle import Screen
from random import random

color = random(), random(), random()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor(color)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Using `colormode()`, you're switching between floating and integer RGB values.

You can also switch to other color models, like HSB, via loading additional Python libraries and converting those color models into RGB for turtle.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that you need a `window`(or whatever variable)`=turtle.Screen()`. Then you can do `window.colormode(255)` Then you can change the color scheme